# Accepting an answer from a question migrated from another site

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I am the OP for [this famous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10750/why-is-debians-root-shell-colorless). It was originally posted to [ServerFault.com](https://serverfault.com/posts/256354/revisions). After 4 years of existence, I think it is time to accept an answer. Turns out that I cannot. Is this by design or a bug?

Comment: Was there ever a bounty on this Q?

Comment: I don't think so. As if! XD

Comment: Yeah I didn't see one for its timeline either, so it's something else. I'll go ask about it upstairs. This is why I asked about bounty: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44114/cannot-mark-accepted-answer-for-one-of-my-questions.

Comment: Get any errors when you try to?

Comment: No, I just don't see the gray tickmark. So I can't select it.

Comment: Try it from a different browser?

Comment: Chrome 39 and IE 11.

Comment: @dmvianna - are you using the Daniel account? That's a diff. acct. than what you're posting to us here with.

Comment: I'm deeply embarrassed. My mistake. :P

Comment: And yet I still have this nagging feeling that I posted that question.

Comment: Totally [different](http://stackexchange.com/users/1597550/dmvianna) [account](http://stackexchange.com/users/131478/daniel), and they don't have any similarities that would suggest you accidentally have two

Comment: Yes, this is not my account. My concern is whether the migration accidentally assigned the question to the wrong Daniel. I know it sounds unlikely. I also know human memory is unreliable.